# How can I define a List to add results of a query in a loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, list, foreach, addition

I have an array filled with long type values and for each value in the array I need to implement a query. I used foreach loop as you can see from the code below:

```
var result;
        foreach(long id in PrdIdArr)
        {
            var mainQuery = (from o in db.OPERATIONs
                             join u in db.UNITs on o.OP_UNIT_ID equals u.UNIT_ID into smt
                             from s in smt
                             join x in db.XIDs on s.UNIT_ID equals x.UNIT_ID
                             where o.OP_OT_CODE == OtCode
                             where x.IDTYP_CD == "BSN"
                             where s.START_PRD_ID == id
                             where o.OP_UPD_DATE >= _StartDate
                             where o.OP_UPD_DATE <= _EndDate
                             select new
                             {
                                 o.OP_ID,
                                 o.OP_UPD_DATE,
                                 x.EXTERNAL_ID,
                                 o.OP_OS_CODE,
                                 o.OP_START,
                                 o.OP_ST_STATION,
                                 s.START_PRD_ID
                             }).Take(_RowNumber);
            //var result = mainQuery.ToList();
            result.add(mainQuery.ToList());
        }

        data = this.Json(result);
        data.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        return data;
```

However, I have a problem in my code; I have to define a main list just before the foreach loop so that I could add results of each query to the that main list. my question is: How can I define this list as you can see at the beginning of my code? Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define this list as you can see at the beginning of my code?

Make

```
new {
     o.OP_ID,
     o.OP_UPD_DATE,
     x.EXTERNAL_ID,
     o.OP_OS_CODE,
     o.OP_START,
     o.OP_ST_STATION,
     s.START_PRD_ID
}
```

into a concrete type (say `QueryResult`, although something a little more specific than that), and then just declare

```
var result = new List<QueryResult>();
```

Also, you should consider turning

```
foreach(long id in PrdIdArr)
```

and

```
where s.START_PRD_ID == id
```

into

```
where PrdIdArr.Contains(s.Start_PRD_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = new List<object>();

    foreach(long id in PrdIdArr)
    {
        ....

        result.Add(mainQuery.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Make sure not to query against the DB directly in your Action Method. Create a Repository class for that. It will help to keep your project clean and focus on what really has to be done within your controllers.

Comment: When I use <object>() it gives the error at the line "result.Add(mainQuery.ToList());"
 : "Systems.Collections.Generic:List<object>'does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type 'Systems.Collections.Generic:List<object>' could be found...."

Comment: "add" has to be "Add"! C# is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry, of course you need to use the method AddRange which will add multiple objects. Add will only add one object.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the anonymous type outside with the same property names and the correct type

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 0).Select(x => new 
             {
               OP_ID = 1,
               OP_UPD_DATE = DateTime.Now,
               EXTERNAL_ID = 1,
               OP_OS_CODE = 1,
               OP_START = DateTIme.Now,
               OP_ST_STATION = "",
               START_PRD_ID = 1,
             }).ToList();
```

And in your loop call `AddRange`

```
result.AddRange(mainQuery.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var result = PrdIdArr.Select(id =>
    from o in db.OPERATIONs
        join u in db.UNITs on o.OP_UNIT_ID equals u.UNIT_ID into smt
        from s in smt
        join x in db.XIDs on s.UNIT_ID equals x.UNIT_ID
        where o.OP_OT_CODE == OtCode
        where x.IDTYP_CD == "BSN"
        where s.START_PRD_ID == id
        where o.OP_UPD_DATE >= _StartDate
        where o.OP_UPD_DATE <= _EndDate
        select new
        {
            o.OP_ID,
            o.OP_UPD_DATE,
            x.EXTERNAL_ID,
            o.OP_OS_CODE,
            o.OP_START,
            o.OP_ST_STATION,
            s.START_PRD_ID
        }
        .Take(_RowNumber)
        .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

I highly recommend performing some [Extract Method](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactorings, as the code is pretty complex and hard to understand/mange this way.